# Select a hidden fields value within a table

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

I have a table, where the user can select samples. In every row there is hidden field, which contains a unique id. I'd like to get selected(checked) row's  hidden field's value in an array, so it can be passed for processing.
So far what I've got:

```
 var data = Array();
 $("#nonScheduledSamples tr").each(function (i) {
     if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
         data[i] = $(this).find("#item_SampleId").val();
     }
 });
```

The table is generated by an MVC partial view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SampleInfo)
{
<tr>
     @Html.HiddenFor(i=>item.SampleId)
     <td class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(i=>i.Selected)</td>
</tr>
}
```

This returns an empty array to me. Any help really appreciated.

**Update #1:** 
I've modified the code, so the html looks like this:

```
<input data-sampleid="60815" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." id="SampleIdSelect" name="SampleInfo[0].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

and the jquery:

```
$("#nonScheduledSamples tr input").each(function () {
     if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
          data.push($("#SampleIdSelect").data("sampleid"));
     }
});
```

At the moment, the data array is filled up with the same value from the data-sampleid but with equal times as many checkbox is ticked. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: The table is generated by an MVC partial view.

Comment: so html will be useful to see what it generated :) Very likely yous SampleInfo array is empty and therefore no rows are generated, you can also check it with debugger

Comment: Data is there, since the table is displayed properly. I am having problems with the jquery part.

Comment: @Paxsentry: inspect element, copy html and then share here

Comment: This is the input fields code generated by the partial view:
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SampleId must be a number." data-val-required="The SampleId field is required." id="item_SampleId" name="item.SampleId" type="hidden" value="60815">

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SampleInfo)
{
<tr>
     @Html.HiddenFor(i=>item.SampleId ,new { @class="item_SampleId"})
     <td class="text-center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(i=>i.Selected)</td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that is not working. I am 100% sure it is a jquery issue not an mvc razor, that is why I hasn't added the tag to it

Answer (score 0):

The final conclusion:

Html:

```
<input data-sampleid="60815" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." id="SampleIdSelect0" name="SampleInfo[0].Selected"  type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Jquery:

```
$("#nonScheduledSamples tr input").each(function () {
     if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
          var x = this.id.slice(14);
          data.push($("#SampleIdSelect" + x).data("sampleid"));
     }
});
```

So slice the id text part, and get the same id's data value, which can be pushed into the array. It was a fight...

Probably there are better solutions, if you have please share.